"Cannot use a session that has ended" error when querying MongoDB
i am trying to get a string from all documents in a mongo db collection, but when it starts it give me an error:
106 |      * not subject to semantic versioning compatibility guarantees and may change at any time.
107 |      *
108 |      * @public
109 |      **/
110 |     constructor(message, options) {
111 |         super(message, options);
              ^
error: Cannot use a session that has ended
      at new MongoError (C:\Users\Utente\Desktop\SkyForce Helper\node_modules\mongodb\lib\error.js:111:9)
      at new MongoDriverError (C:\Users\Utente\Desktop\SkyForce Helper\node_modules\mongodb\lib\error.js:209:9)
      at new MongoAPIError (C:\Users\Utente\Desktop\SkyForce Helper\node_modules\mongodb\lib\error.js:238:9)
      at new MongoExpiredSessionError (C:\Users\Utente\Desktop\SkyForce Helper\node_modules\mongodb\lib\error.js:403:9)
      at applySession (C:\Users\Utente\Desktop\SkyForce Helper\node_modules\mongodb\lib\sessions.js:708:16)
      at prepareCommand (C:\Users\Utente\Desktop\SkyForce Helper\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connection.js:169:49)
      at C:\Users\Utente\Desktop\SkyForce Helper\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connection.js:259:30
      at C:\Users\Utente\Desktop\SkyForce Helper\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connection.js:313:26
      at command (C:\Users\Utente\Desktop\SkyForce Helper\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connection.js:311:23)
      at C:\Users\Utente\Desktop\SkyForce Helper\node_modules\mongodb\lib\sdam\server.js:167:40

my function:
export async function returnAllRep(): Promise<string[]> {
    const { client, database } = await connectToDatabase();
    const collection = database.collection('chains'); 
    
    try {
        const docs = await collection.find().toArray();
        
        const ids = docs.map(doc => doc.id);
        
        return ids;
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Errore durante la recuperazione dei documenti:', error);
        throw error;
    } finally {
        await client.close();
    }
}

I have trying to add debug when it connect to the db, it says it's connected but then it crash
If i try with a single  document it works, but i need all the document

Why close the connection client.close(); when you want to reuse it? Open it, and keep it open. Post the code of connectToDatabase

To connect your client to the MongoDB cluster, and retrieve your database, I would use the following syntax instead.
import { MongoClient } from "mongodb";

// Define your connection string and database
const MONGODB_URI = "<connection string>";
const DATABASE = "<database name>";

// Connect to the client and get your collection object
const client = await MongoClient.connect(MONGODB_URI);
const collection = client.db(DATABASE).collection("chains");

const docs = await collection.find().toArray();

It seems like the way you are getting the database is different.

I connect with another file, but in the other file the connection is like this, but it still doesn't work. I have another functions like this and all works, so i tink the problem is when i try to get multiple data
